# second window restores only into WindowState.Normal

Tags: c#, wpf

I place a child window on the 2nd screen on startup. But after minimizing the main window when I maximize it again the child window gets the window state `Normal`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var childWindow = new Window();
        childWindow.Owner = this;
        childWindow.Left = 2400;
        childWindow.Top = 0;
        childWindow.Loaded += OnWindowLoaded; // ensure maximizing on the second screen
        childWindow.Show();
    }

    private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = sender as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried set to `Maximized` when the main window's state changed, but without success. How can I prevent setting the 2nd window to `Normal`?

Comment: i don't see you calling `childWindow.Show()` anywhere by the way ..?

Comment: just added it...

Comment: Where do you call this code ? var childwindo... ? In my case, it works. I think there is another piece of code which causes the problem. Can you post the method in which you call this code ?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul is right. and also `OnWindowLoaded` event will be called only once at startup and will maximize child window and then it should stay same until manually state is changed !

Comment: added the complete code. On start everything is ok. But minimize the main window first and then restore it again. What is childs state now?

Comment: Haven't tried this but ..won't this work ? in `MainWindow` `OnsizeChanged` event check if `MainWindow` state is max then set `ChildWindow.State = WindowState.Maximized` and if `MainWindow` Satate is Min then You can set `ChildWindow` state to min or max.. depending on your need ???